# Which ESLint rule applies to Promise/Arrow function indent?

Tags: javascript, eslint

I have the following code snippet:

```
const enclosing = () => {
  const setClaim = (userId, claim) => {
    client
      .setClaim({ userId, claim })
      .then(() => {
          // do something

          return resolve(true);
        }, // eslint complains about this line
        err => reject(err)
      );
  });
};
```

ESLint complains about the line marked above as follows:

```
139:9   error  Expected indentation of 6 spaces but found 8                  indent
```

Which `indent` rule object option does apply here (has to be changed) as I want to keep the indentation as is?

I don't want to suppress the ESLint error using `eslint-disable-line` as this is a global (applies to all of my code being linted) issue for me.

Comment: It is the `indent` rule.

Comment: I would be more concerned about the mismatched parenthesis `)` on the second-to-last line…

Comment: One has to admit, that's a really weird indentation. Are you going to do this consistently for all multiline arguments, or only when it's a function, or only when there are multiple functions?

Comment: Yes, I think this is the root cause (done by WebStorm)

Answer (score 12):

In case you arrived here looking for Promise Indent answers like I did (see title)... The MemberExpression section of [ESLint Indent rules](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/indent) may be helpful. Member expression "enforces indentation level for multi-line property chains".

You can turn off checking for indentation of chained methods by setting `"MemberExpression"` to `"Off"` in your `.eslintrc.js` file.

```
rules: {
  'indent': ['error', 4, { 'MemberExpression': 'off'}]
}
```

With MemberExpression set to "off", you can write your promises indented, or lined-up.

**Lined Up**

```
client
.setClaim({ userId, claim })
.then(resolve(true), reject)
```

**Indented**

```
client
    .setClaim({ userId, claim })
    .then(resolve(true), reject)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const enclosing = () => {
  const setClaim = (userId, claim) => {
    client
      .setClaim({ userId, claim })
      .then(() => {
         // ^ insert a newline here
          // do something

          return resolve(true);
        }, // eslint complains about this line
        err => reject(err)
      );
  });
};
```

I suggest adding a new line before the fulfill handler. Since you give `.then` two handlers, doing so can keep them at the same indentation level.